# Routes: Check if session exists in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So in my `LoginController.php,` I started a session for different `post request variables` below where the session code is inside the authenticated function of auth.

```
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user){
     $request->session()->put('param1',$param1);
     $request->session()->put('param2',$param2);
     $request->session()->put('param3',$param3);
     .....
 }
```

and I easily access these session in my different controllers like this

`$request->session()->get('param1')`

and I also placed this code when logout triggers..

`session()->flush();`

But I need also to protect my `route` if these `session exists` or `not`

What I'm trying to do is to not allow the users not to access these routes if session is not exists **web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware'=> ['auth']], function(){

Route::get('/pay', 'PayController@index');
Route::post('pay/getReceipt', 'PayController@getReceipt')->name('getReceipt');
....

});
```

Comment: laravel does have StartSession middleware. If your routes call that middleware, the session is started every request

Answer (score 5):

Create a middleware that checks if those session parameters exist then wrap your routes in it.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Session::has('your_params')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```